# Combination of two characters

Tags: c#, combinations

I am giving input as int and according to that input I want combination of two characters,
**FOR EXAMPLE**
 I am giving input as 2 and I have two characters x and y so I want combinations like

```
    xx,yy,xy,yx
```

If Input is 3,I want

```
    xxx,xyy,xxy,xyx,yxx,yyy,yxy.yyx
```

and so on,I have try with following code,

```
     int input1 = 4;
        Double totalpossibilities = Math.Pow(2, input1);
        string[] PArray = new string[Convert.ToInt16(totalpossibilities)];
        char[] chars = new char[] { 'x', 'y'};

        for (int i = 0; i < totalpossibilities; i++)
        {
            string possibility = "" ;
            for (int j = 0; j < input1; j++)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                int r = random.Next(chars.Length);
                char randomChar = chars[r];
                possibility = possibility + randomChar;

            }
            if (PArray.Contains(possibility))
            {
                i--;
            }
            else
                PArray[i] = possibility;
        }
```

But as you can see I am using random function So I takes too long to complete,Is there any different logic?

Comment: Try extracting the initialization of `random` to the beginning of your program...or do you want a new seed every iteration?

Comment: He should not use random at all to solve this problem.

Comment: @Magnus I know I should not use random ,But is there any way to get permutations?can you help for that?

Comment: @Hiren, Servy has a good answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run a for loop from 0 to totalpossibilities.
Convert i to binary, for example, at iteration 20 this would result in "10100".
Pad the result to input1 characters, for example (for 8 places): 00010100
Then convert to a string and replace all zeroes with "x", all ones with "y".

```
        int places = 4;
        Double totalpossibilities = Math.Pow(2, places);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalpossibilities; i++)
        {
            string CurrentNumberBinary = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(places, '0');

            CurrentNumberBinary = CurrentNumberBinary.Replace('0', 'x');
            CurrentNumberBinary = CurrentNumberBinary.Replace('1', 'y');
            Debug.WriteLine(CurrentNumberBinary);
        }
```

Comment: I understand ,But I dont want to use Random function because suppose input is 200,it will take really long to complete

Comment: The number of possible string is 2^n. The maximum input you can solve in a lifetime is probably less than 32.

Comment: Interesting solution. But since `Convert.ToString(Int32, Int32)` does not work for ternary, quaternary etc. it does not work well with three, four etc. letters. I wrote another "solution".

Answer (score 4):

Using a copy of the Cartesian Product extension method copied verbatim from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

Then in your code you can have:

```
IEnumerable<char> possibleCharacters = "xy";//change to whatever
int numberOfDigits = 3;

var result = Enumerable.Repeat(possibleCharacters, numberOfDigits)
     .CartesianProduct()
     .Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()));

//display (or do whatever with) the results
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Added a `Select` at the end so that you have an enumeration of strings, which might be easier for you to deal with.  You can remove that select at the end if you would rather have an enumeration of enumeration of characters.

Comment: Do I need to make any change with this code? I use same code but I am getting error in var result = Enumerable.Repeat(possibleCharacters, numberOfDigits)
     .CartesianProduct()
     .Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()));
Does not contain defination of 'CartesianProduct'

Comment: The Cartesian product method will need to be in a static class, since it's an extension method.  You could refactor it to just be a regular static method if you wanted as well.

Comment: I accept svenv's answer but also upvote your answer,Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

if you always have 2 characters then the simplest way is to use the integers combinatorial nature. if you take the binary form of all numbers from 2^n to 2^(n+1) - 1, you will notice that it represents all the possible combination of '0' and '1' of length n :).

For more than 2 characters, I'll use a similar approach but with a different base.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `List<>`. Generalizes to any number of letters.

```
static List<string> letters = new List<string> { "x", "y", };

static List<string> MakeList(int input)
{
  if (input < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

  var li = new List<string> { "", };

  for (int i = 0; i < input; ++i)
    li = Multiply(li);

  return li;
}

static List<string> Multiply(List<string> origList)
{
  var resultList = new List<string>(origList.Count * letters.Count);
  foreach (var letter in letters)
    resultList.AddRange(origList.Select(s => letter + s));
  return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

svenv answer is the correct (and very clever) answer to the question, but I thought I'd provide a generic solution to generating all permutations of set of tokens which might be useful for others who might have a similar problem.

```
public class Permutations
{
    public static string[][] GenerateAllPermutations(string[] tokens, int depth)
    {
        string[][] permutations = new string[depth][];

        permutations[0] = tokens;

        for (int i = 1; i < depth; i++)
        {
            string[] parent = permutations[i - 1];
            string[] current = new string[parent.Length * tokens.Length];

            for (int parentNdx = 0; parentNdx < parent.Length; parentNdx++)
                for (int tokenNdx = 0; tokenNdx < tokens.Length; tokenNdx++)
                    current[parentNdx * tokens.Length + tokenNdx] = parent[parentNdx] + tokens[tokenNdx];

            permutations[i] = current;
        }

        return permutations;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        string[] tokens = new string[] { "x", "y", "z" };
        int depth = 4;

        string[][] permutations = GenerateAllPermutations(tokens, depth);

        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        {
            foreach (string s in permutations[i])
                Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total permutations:  {0}", permutations[i].Length));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers,